# Where should I have two consecutive empty pages when applying for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, passports

I am applying for Schengen visa soon. I have two consecutive pages on passport but they are almost in the front. Page no 4-5 are blank in 34 pages passport. Is it still fine?

I know there are lots of questions around two consecutive pages, but just to confirm one additional condition I am asking this question.

Comment: Why would it not be fine?

Comment: Just making sure because the second country I applied visa for missed those pages and all the visa I got later never used those pages. And saw someone asking about the chronological order on stamps. Thought might be needed in visa too. @kuba

Comment: There's no chronological order requirement for visas and entry stamp that I've heard of. I've been denied a visa for not having a two opposing consecutive empty pages (by Kosovo), while the UK only requires two consecutive pages back to back. But never heard of a chronological order of visas being an issue ever

Comment: got visa today. I had two consecutive blank page in the front and a page with just one blank side in the end. Got visa in the end.

Answer (score 1):

According to OP:

> Got visa today. I had two consecutive blank page in the front and a page with just one blank side in the end. Got visa in the end.